# test runs with eclipse but not with maven

Tags: linux, eclipse, maven, junit, swt

I have an editor page in my RCP application. If I right click within the editor, a context (swt widget) menu opens. This context menu has the items "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4".

I have a SWTBot test, which checks if all context menu items are available. The test look somehow like this (modified for debugging issues):

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu menu = getMenu();
for (MenuItem item : menu.getItems()) {
   System.out.println("[DEBUG]" + item.getText());
}
```

If i run this test on Windows XP within Eclipse or maven, the console prints item1 - item4. If i run this test on a Linux machine within eclipse the output is equals to windows. But if i run the test with MAVEN on LINUX, the output is like "item2" and "item4". Item1 and item3 are missing!

I have no idea why. Does anyone have one?

Thanks in advance

Versions:
Windows XP 64bit SP2,
Linux with Xfce 4.6 connected with VNC server,
Maven 3.0.3 (on both machines)